# Multiple Charts Same Plot

Tags: r

How do you maintain a different # of charts in 2 different rows. For instance, I want 1 chart in row 1 and 10 charts in row 2. How do I do this?

The closest I've gotten is :

```
> par(mfrow=c(2,1))
> x=c(1,2,3324,324)
> y=c(1,2,32,2323)
> plot(x,y)
> plot(x,y)
```

This creates 1 chart on top of the other, but I can't get the 2nd row to be able to handle 10 charts

Comment: You want to nest. Take a look at layout

Answer (score 3, accepted):

using `layout`, it is easy once you create the right matrix

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
[1,]    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1    1     1
[2,]    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10    11


layout(matrix(c(rep(1,10),2:11),nrow=2,byrow=T))
 x=c(1,2,3324,324)
 y=c(1,2,32,2323)
 plot(x,y)
 replicate(n=10,plot(x,y))
```

[image]

**EDIT** give different widths

```
mat <- matrix(c(rep(1,10),2:11),nrow=2,byrow=T)
layout(mat, widths = c(rep(1,5),rep(2,3),rep(3,2)))
```

I like the `layout.show` function. It is very convenient to control your layout.

```
layout.show(n = 11)
```

[image]

Comment: thank you, great example. I've been look at the documentation but is there any way to select a different width for each of the bottom 10 graphs? or is this not possible?

Comment: I'm asking this because if I direct copy and paste to test those lines above that you posted, I get : Error in plot.new() : figure margins too large

Comment: @Django the error you get it is not on relation with the widths. Try to clear your plots ( clear all if your using Rsutudio)

Comment: @Django **figure margins too large  error** comes when the plot pane in RStudio is too small, try increasing dimensions of the plot pane in RStudio, the error should go away